# How to find the Jira issues that fall between a Number Range

Tags: jira

As a user, I want to be able to search for issues that fall into a range criteria.
example

- issues with ticket number that is between ticket001 and ticket025
- Issues which their creation date is between 01-01-2015 and Current Date

Answer (score 6):

First question:

You can use your project id to search for those issues:

```
id >= XY-100 AND id <= XY-150
```

This search will list all project ids from XY between 100 and 150.

Second question:

For the second kind of question you can use a search string like this:

```
createdDate <= "2015/03/01" AND createdDate >= "2015/01/01"
```

For your specific problem you can just use the following:

```
createdDate >= "2015/01/01"
```

Comment: Although useful, the `id >= XY-100 AND id <= XY-150` query unfortunately does work if either one of the endpoint issues doesn't exist for some reason (deleted, or not created yet). I don't know a workaround for this at the moment. Just be careful if automating this and expecting it to work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `created` or `createdDate`

Supported Operators:

```
=
!=
>
>=
<
<=
IS
IS NOT
IN
NOT IN
```

Find all issues created on 12th December 2010 before 2:00pm:

```
created > "2010/12/12" and created < "2010/12/12 14:00"
```